# What is the purpose of :after?

Tags: html, css

I have seen lately many `:after` in front-end css and to me it seems like `:hover` but there's must be a difference so I want to understand exactly How it works/applies?
Thanks very much.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: research is your friend - this is a very common pseudo-selector so you will not have any trouble finding out about it.  You need to do some work in understanding new concepts rather than asking members of SO to just tell you all the answers

Comment: :before = pseudo-seector for the state of unknowing prior to the research state and :research is the pseudo-selector for undertaking a pursuit of awareness and :after is the pseudo-selector for the state of knowing following your research :)

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: Please research first before post your question.

Answer (score 2):

> A pseudo-element does exactly what the word implies. It creates a
>   phoney element and inserts it before or after the content of the
>   element that you’ve targeted. The word "pseudo" is a transliteration
>   of a Greek word that basically means "lying, deceitful, false." So,
>   calling them pseudo-elements is appropriate, because they don’t
>   actually change anything in the document. Rather, they insert
>   ghost-like elements that are visible to the user and that are
>   style-able in the CSS.
>
> **Basic Syntax**
>
> The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are very easy to code (as are most CSS properties that don’t require a ton
>   of vendor prefixes). Here is a simple **example:**
>
> ```
> #example:before {
>    content: "#";
> }
>
> #example:after {
>    content: ".";
> }
> ```

**[source](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)**

Comment: Is it keeps the same css style as the #example?

Answer (score 0):

It is used to insert something **after** a given element.

```
p::after { 
    content: " - Remember this";
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp).
And in [action](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_after).

Comment: actually take care with this :after is a pseudo-selector and ::after is a pseudo-element  -not quite the same thing

Comment: Doesn't exist  something called pseudo-selector, `:after` and `::after` are the same pseudo-element with different syntax. From MDN: "The `::after` notation (with two colons) was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. "

Comment: Is it keeps the same css style as the p element? what is the purpose of it at all?